# 1st order ODE separable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

everyone! :-)

I've a ODE question with I can't solve. It's here:
${dy\over dx} = {{xy + 2y-x-2}\over {xy-3y+x-3}} $

I tried the following:

${dy\over dx} = {{xy + 2y-x-2}\over {xy-3y+x-3}}={(y-1)(x+2)\over (y+1)(x-3)} \Rightarrow \int {(y+1)dy\over(y-1)}=\int {(x+2)dx\over(x-3)}\ \ \ $    This has resulted in:

$\int {(y)dy\over(y-1)}+\int {dy\over(y-1)}=\int {(x)dx\over(x-2)}+2\int {dx\over(x-3)} \Rightarrow y+2ln|y-1|=x+5ln|x-3|$

I can not explain the function $y$. Can anyone help me showing how I do it? Thanks!

Comment: $y+2\ln\lvert y-1\rvert = \ln((y-1)^2e^y)$. Unfortunately, this involves solving $we^w = z$, which requires [a special function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). BTW, your indefinite integral is missing the "$+C$".